# Apache tomcat https not showing

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, https

I've updated my webapp from a previous version, so I had to recofigure the tomcat server. When I point my browser to *localhost:8080* it works fine, but when I've enabled *https* at *server.xml*, and I point my browser to *localhost:8443* it's not presenting the login page, instead it tries to download an empty file:

**server.xml**:

```
 <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150"
  minSpareThreads="25" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"
  useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>

  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
  connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
  keystoreFile="*masked*" keystorePass="*masked*" keystoreType="JKS"
  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" port="8443"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https" secure="true"
  sslProtocol="TLS" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

I can find the port up and running, and no errors at **catalina.log**:

```
Mar 30, 2014 12:09:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA 4.3\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;.

Mar 30, 2014 12:09:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Mar 30, 2014 12:09:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]

Mar 30, 2014 12:09:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 1365 ms

Mar 30, 2014 12:09:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Mar 30, 2014 12:09:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

I can't find what I'm missing, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because HTTPS requires a certificate?  I've never used Tomcat with SSL directly, but always put IIS in front, installed the certificate in IIS, and used Tomcat Connector to bridge the two.

Comment: The certificate is installed (keystoreFile="*masked*" keystorePass="*masked*" keystoreType="JKS"), and is not showing any error of it at catalina.log. Previously I was using it directly with with Tomcat without issues.